# can't make jquery.bgswitcher works

Tags: jquery, background

Trying to make a background slider using jquery bgswitcher.
My code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script src="js/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>

<script>
    $(".wrapper").bgswitcher({
        images: ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.png", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.png"],
        effect: "fade",
        interval: 5000,
        loop: false,
        shuffle: false,
        duration: 5000,
        easing: "swing"
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code, but the background slider doesn't work!
Any idea?

Comment: try `loop: false  ` to `loop: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the bgswitcher in document.ready...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".wrapper").bgswitcher({
images: ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.png", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.png"], 
effect: "fade", 
interval: 5000, 
loop: false, 
shuffle: false, 
duration: 5000, 
easing: "swing"
});

});
</script>
```