# $(...).bcatBGSwitcher is not being defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, background

Everything works fine in the example, but when I try to run the same code inside an ASP MVC5 project, I get the following javascript error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bcatBGSwitcher is not a function".

at this line:

> $('#bgswitcher').bcatBGSwitcher({

This is the _Layout.cshtml related code:

```
<head>

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/bgswitcher/js/jquery.bcat.bgswitcher.js")"></script>

    ...

</head>
```

And this is the view related code:

```
...

<div id="bgswitcher"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var srcBgArray = ['@Url.Content("~/Content/galleries/bar/im1.png")', '@Url.Content("~/Content/galleries/bar/im2.png")', '@Url.Content("~/Content/galleries/bar/im3.png")'];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bgswitcher').bcatBGSwitcher({
            urls: srcBgArray,
            alt: 'Full screen background image',
            links: true,
            prevnext: true
        });
    });

</script>

...
```

There is no more errors in the console, and all scripts and CSS's are being loaded properly.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525492/cant-make-jquery-bgswitcher-works/18525525), but the answer is not valid for my problem.